# 'sed' is not replacing matching sequence in file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have input like this in a specific file

```
#- seeds: "12.123.233.213,123.231.3.2"
    - seeds: "12.12.21.21,43.435.54.54"
```

As you see that the seeds contains two consecutive IP addresses, so I want to change that IP address in the file. 1st line will not be considered as it starts with "#"

So for doing this, I have this:

```
val=' - seeds: "'

newSeed=${val}${ip1}','${ip2}'"'     # ---> I'm creating the new seed
str=`grep "\s- seed" $file`          # ---> finding matching character
echo $str                            # ---> it does print out the 2nd line
sed -i 's|${str}|${newSeed}|g' $file # --> now replace the matched string with new seed value
```

But it doesn't replace the value in the file. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes do not expand variable names. Use double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need double quote for bash to expand variables.

`sed -i "s/${str}/${newSeed}/g"`

Comment: Oh, I missed it! Thanks a lot choroba & sudo_o